# Creating new mean columns for multliple files using loop using python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I've got this dataframe that looks like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[230,345,222],'':[235,375,292],'B':[210,385,260],' ':[235,378,292],'C':[255,379,333],'D':[555,321,121],'E':[999,123,333],'  ':[1231,1231,222]})
     A               B               C       D       E  
0   230     235     210     235     255     555     999     1231
1   345     375     385     378     379     321     123     1231
2   222     292     260     292     333     121     333     222
```

I want to make means columns for each parameter because the parameter like A, B, and E have 2 column that have values in it. So far, I can only make 1 parameter columns and got lost when I want to create parameter for another columns. The code is below

```
dflist=pd.DataFrame()
for i, file in enumerate(flist):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows = [0,1,3,4])
    data = df.iloc[:,1:2]
    dflist['A%i'%i] = data.mean(axis=1)
```

I want the result to be somewhat like this.

```
     A              Aavg     B              Bavg     C       D        E            Eavg
0   230     235     123     210     235     123     255     555     999     1231    111
1   345     375     456     385     378     324     379     321     123     1231    222
2   222     292     333     260     292     1231    333     121     333     222     333
```

Any help would be appreciated

Edit :
My csv files look likes this
[image]

Comment: _I want to make means coloumns for each parameter because the parameter like A, B, and E have 2 coloumn that have values in it._ Why not merge the columns, or find another way to fix that issue? Also, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: is the mean value in your example a calculated number or just for example a random number? (230+235)/2 isnt 123

Comment: @anky_91it's just a random number

Comment: @AMC because this is the best way to do my tasks.

Comment: @ojasony If you say so.

Answer (score 0):

You are not indexing your columns properly. Proper indexing would look something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    ('A', 1):[230,345,222],
    ('A', 2):[235,375,292],
    ('B', 1):[210,385,260],
    ('B', 2):[235,378,292],
    ('C', 1):[255,379,333],
    ('D', 1):[555,321,121],
    ('E', 1):[999,123,333],
    ('E', 2):[1231,1231,222]
})

    A         B         C    D    E      
    1    2    1    2    1    1    1     2
0  230  235  210  235  255  555  999  1231
1  345  375  385  378  379  321  123  1231
2  222  292  260  292  333  121  333   222
```

Then you can average by column very easily:

```
df.mean(level=0, axis=1)

       A      B      C      D       E
0  232.5  222.5  255.0  555.0  1115.0
1  360.0  381.5  379.0  321.0   677.0
2  257.0  276.0  333.0  121.0   277.5
```

---

If you have no control over the data format, you can treat each blank-named column as a continuation of the previous column:

```
col_group = df.columns.to_series() \
                .str.strip() \
                .replace('')

df.groupby(col_group, axis=1).mean()
```

The `replace` function looks deceptively simple but it's actually doing 2 things at the same time: (1) replace blank column names with `None`; (2) fill those `None`s with the last non-null column name (via `method='pad'` default param).

Comment: I tried to use the groupby but got an "No numeric types to aggregate" error and yes I have no control over the data format, that's why i refer to this